# Can I create a specific rule for a column(s)?

Tags: html, css, styles, multiple-columns

I have created 3 different sets of columns, but I want the ability to style each column differently.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="first">
        <div class="column">Featured Work</div>
        <div class="column">info</div>    
        <div class="column">info</div>
    </div>

    <div class="middle">
        <div class="column">News</div>
        <div class="column">middle column</div>    
        <div class="column">right column</div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="column">body copy 1</div>
        <div class="column">body copy 2</div>    
        <div class="column">body copy 3</div>
    </div>
```

this is my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/Cj6dj/2/

I want to style the `featured work` and `news` columns with top and bottom boarders and to style the type. The two `Info` columns along with the `middle` and `Right` columns would have full boarder around it.

Would I rename each class to a unique name to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you the `:first-child` selector - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cj6dj/4/)

```css
#container .first div.column:first-child,
#container .middle div.column:first-child {
    border-width: 1px 0;
    color: #c00;
}
```

Comment: correct, but how can I remove the style you created away from the last set of columns?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Cj6dj/4/ I have a boarder around the two "info" columns which i need. but the "middle column," "Right column," and all of the "body copy" columns i want no boarder around them. How can i create a rule to do this?